# how to center a div on a page

Tags: php, css, centering

how to put a div on the horizental center of a page. this div to display a image.
I want to display that image on center, and  without fixed size.plus this div should be display on top of other div.

in this case, I want to do it without doing anything about that width of div or image.

I tried some examples, but failed.

what mistake I am doing? I am bit confused. please help

```
     #dart{
        position: absolute;   
        top: 10px;         
        margin: auto;       
        z-index: 10000;    
        margin-left: auto ;
        margin-right: auto ;    
      }

    .darts{
        height: 80%;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto 
         }

      <div id="dart">
        <img id="darts" src="../darts.png"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: @Obsidion the div has the ID dart. the image has the ID Darts.

Comment: The css has class darts

Comment: for dart , I changed it to  position: relative;
  text-align:center;  that worked, I don't know why, hehe..